# Custom Service Account on IIS application pool not working by removing from Administrator of Computer Management

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis-7

If I remove custom service account from computer Management Administrator then application throwing 503 Service unavailable error but if I add service account to Administrator group under Computer Management of Server then work fine

Comment: Is that a question? If you created the application you should know specifically what access you need to give the account.

Comment: @Crowcoder Requirement is to connect sql server with website using service account with windows authetication mode . I have added all permission on sql server and inetpub, wwwroot folders on IIS server , login as batch , impersonate permission but stills showing 503 service unavailable error when using service account in the identity of application pool

Comment: A normal IIS site only requires a few basic user rights and permissions, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/iis/www-authentication-authorization/default-permissions-user-rights and local administrator group membership is never required by default. You have to ask the developer(s) of the web application on why 503 occurs and local administrator is required. Only they can answer that for you.

Comment: 503 error is often an ambiguous one. Many reasons can cause this “service unavailable error”. I suggest you check the web server logs first.